# Clash of clan API error response while fetching the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

> VM100:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'E', "Error: " is not valid JSON 
> at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) 
> at Object.success (ajax.js:15:21)     
> at c (Jquery.js:2:25266)     
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (Jquery.js:2:26015)     
> at l (Jquery.js:2:77721)     
> at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (Jquery.js:2:80204)

My PHP Code is

```
<?php

$apiKey = file_get_contents('./token.txt');
$playerTag = '%23'.$_GET['tag'];



$url = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/{$playerTag}";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'F:\Programming\Wamp\www\clashofclan\cacert.pem');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = $response;



if ($response === false) 
{
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} 
else {
    
    if (isset($data)) 
    {
        $dataEn = json_encode($data);
        echo $dataEn;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Error: Unable to fetch player information.';
    }
}
?>
```

In Ajax / JS

```
// 9CQ8R2J89
$('#submit').click(function()
{ 
  

  tag = $('#tag').val()
  tag = tag.toUpperCase();
  $.ajax({
    
     url : './get.php',
     method : 'GET',
     data: { tag: tag },
     success : function(res)
     {
        main = JSON.parse(res)
      $('#res').html(main);
     }

  })

})
```

I tried every thing best of my knowledge , & also tried chat-gpt but still the error continues again & again

Comment: The response you're getting isn't valid JSON. It's most likely an error message. I'd suggest checking what the actual response text is in the network tab of devtools

Comment: Start by changing your echo of errors into a valid JSON string so you can actually do a `main = JSON.parse(res)` on those responses too. And then in the JS actually look for those error situations before assuming all is well

Answer (score 0):

First make all your responses into JSON, the first thing your JS code does is attempt to convert the response JSON into js data. If its getting an error that line will fail like this

```
if ($response === false) 
{
    echo json_encode( ['errorCode => 1, 
                       'errorMsg' => curl_error($ch)
                      ] 
                    );
} else {
    
    if (isset($data)) 
    {
        echo json_encode(['errorCode' => 0,
                          'response' => $data);
    } else  {
        echo json_encode( ['errorCode => 2, 
                           'errorMsg' => 'Unable to fetch player information.'
                          ] 
                        );
    }
}
```

Now in the Javascript, look for errors before anything else otherwise continue with the main process

```
$('#submit').click(function(){ 
    tag = $('#tag').val();
    tag = tag.toUpperCase();
    $.ajax({
        url : './get.php',
        method : 'GET',
        data: { tag: tag },
        success : function(res) {
            main = JSON.parse(res);
            if ( main.errorCode == 0){
                $('#res').html(main);
            } else {
                // error found, so do whatever is necessary here
        }
    });
});
```

> Also note the additional `;`'s